# How can I use vector displacement like this streamer?

Tags: materials

[image]

When I see Youtube video, the streamer's displacement material rises highly enough.

But when I try same thing, my displacement material do not rise like his.

Below my work

[image]

How can I raise brick material from surface like that guy?

Comment: Have you enabled Properties > Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement and choose Displacement Only or Displacement and Bump?

Comment: I see that 'bump only' is chosen as default. After subdividing object, displacement raised surface material enough. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to enable the displacement in the material setting[image]

Comment: thank you my good friend